# How do you clear the persistent storage for a notebook instance on AWS SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, storage, amazon-sagemaker

So I'm running into the following error on AWS SageMaker when trying to save:

> Unexpected error while saving file: untitled.ipynb [Errno 28] No space left on device

If I remove my notebook, create a new identical one and run it, everything works fine. However, I'm suspecting the Jupyter checkpoint takes up too much space if I save the notebook while it's running and therefore I'm running out of space. Sadly, getting more storage is not an option for me, so I'm wondering if there's any command I can use to clear the storage before running my notebook?

More specifically, clearing the persistent storage in the beginning and at the end of the training process.

I have googled like a maniac but there is no suggestion aside from "just increase the amount of storage bro" and that's why I'm asking the question here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your data to be persistent across multiple notebook runs, just store them in `/tmp` which is not persistent. You have at least 10GB. More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/howitworks-create-ws.html).

Comment: Okay so how exactly do I choose to store it there? And how can I clear what's persisted across multiple notebook runs?

Comment: Whenever you save something in your code, simply do it in `/tmp` folder.. or try to change the working directory using `os.chdir(NEW_PATH)`. `/tmp` get automatically cleared by AWS at each notebook launch, you don't have to worry about it. Another approach (if you don't want to use `/tmp` is that you manually delete you files at the end of the work, consider that by default you directory is `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker`

Comment: Would you please accept accept my answer if that helps? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your storage is full, you can try deleting some files which are not required. I did this and it worked for me.

First type: `df -h` in your terminal.

You will get output something like this:

```
(base) studio-lab-user@default:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          27G   64K   27G   1% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm             4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1   50G   15G   36G  29% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
/dev/nvme2n1     25G   23G  2.6G  90% /home/studio-lab-user
devtmpfs        7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs           7.7G   12K  7.7G   1% /proc/driver/nvidia
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

As you can see here "/home/studio-lab-user" is mounted for users and available space is only 2.6 gb so to delete unnecessary files.

Type this in terminal `du -h --max-depth=1 /home/studio-lab-user`

```
(base) studio-lab-user@default:~$ du -h --max-depth=1 /home/studio-lab-user
14G     /home/studio-lab-user/.conda
249M    /home/studio-lab-user/.local
44K     /home/studio-lab-user/.ipython
16K     /home/studio-lab-user/.jupyter
8.1G    /home/studio-lab-user/.cache
4.0K    /home/studio-lab-user/.keras
4.0K    /home/studio-lab-user/.ipynb_checkpoints
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.nv
756K    /home/studio-lab-user/.config
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.sagemaker
0       /home/studio-lab-user/.virtual_documents
23G     /home/studio-lab-user
```

All files will be listed in size order, you can delete them using `rm -r /path/to/folder` like `rm -r /home/studio-lab-user/.conda`.

Warning: If you delete the /home/studio-lab-user/.conda you might loose your conda envs you have created.

And by this way you can delete other files and clear your storage , also after deleting you can check storage using `df -h` by typing in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and was not unable to find a decent answer to it online. However, I was fortunately able to resolve the issue.

I use an R kernel, so the solution might be slightly different.

You can check the storage going in the terminal and typing `db -kh`
You are likely mounted on the /home/ec2-user/SageMaker and can see its "Size"  "Used" "Avail" and "Use%".

There are hidden folders that function as a recycle bin. When I use R command `list.dirs()` it reveals a folder named ./.Trash-1000/ which kept a lot of random things that had been supposedly removed from the storage.
I just deleted the folder `unlink('./.Trash-1000/', recursive = T)` and it the entire storage was freed.

Hope it helps.